# How to find the path of a changing directory name?

Tags: python, regex, firefox, ubuntu

I want to access the following path on Ubuntu in my python code:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/dh4ytbdj.default/bookmarkbackups
```

which contains Firefox bookmarks

The problem is that the part before the '`.default`' is different for every user and machine.
Is there a way that I can specify a general path for this directory and make python access it and retrieve the desired file?

And is it possible to implement the '`~`' in python code to access current user's home?

Comment: I apologize for that, thank you

Comment: No problem .. I had to learn this too. The more readable the post, the more likely an answer will emerge as I've found out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/.mozilla/firefox/dh4ytbdj.default/bookmarkbackups')
'/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/dh4ytbdj.default/bookmarkbackups'
```

For system-wide access of personal firefox directories (with sufficient rights) you could try:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/bookmarkbackups')
```

As @NedBatchelder noted, this can be combined into one command:

```
import os, glob
next(glob.iglob(os.path.expanduser('~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/bookmarkbackups')))
```

which returns one (if existing) path.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the '~' thing, still can't make it access whatever the name before the '.default'

Comment: @user1239277 - does the wildcard solution with `glob` work for you?

Comment: Might as well combine the two:  `glob.glob(os.path.expanduser("~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/bla"))`.

Comment: @eumiro: The OP said `~` and "current user's home directory."